# Dynamic Jasper program Deployment Run time error: no source files

Tags: java, dynamic-jasper

Anybody have experience deploying Dynamic Jasper in a java program wrapper used by other java programs?  I have successfully deployed a Jasper Reports wrapper but get the following error when doing the same with Dynamic Jasper.

> Nov 11, 2021 9:28:08 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper
> generateJasperPrint INFO: generating JasperPrint Nov 11, 2021 9:28:08
> AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper generateJasperReport INFO:
> generating JasperReport (DynamicReport dr, LayoutManager
> layoutManager, Map generatedParams) Nov 11, 2021 9:28:08 AM
> ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper generateJasperReport INFO:
> generating JasperReport with prefix: r Nov 11, 2021 9:28:08 AM
> ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DJJRDesignHelper getNewDesign INFO: Creating
> DynamicJasperDesign Errors were encountered when compiling report
> expressions class file: error: no source files

The java program is simple - it works just fine on it's own but fails when deployed and called by another java program.  There is a template option in Jasper Reports.  I have deployed with and without the template and get the same error.  I also get the same error with the ClassicLayoutManager.

Here is key code ...

```
            DynamicReportBuilder reportBuilder = new DynamicReportBuilder();

            Page page = Page.Page_Letter_Portrait();

            reportBuilder.setTitle(reportTitle)
                    .setPageSizeAndOrientation(page)
                    .setUseFullPageWidth(true)
                    .setMargins(30, 20, 30, 15)
                    .setReportName("PrintPage Report Name")
                    .setColumnsPerPage(1);

            //"Field"
            AbstractColumn columnField =
                    ColumnBuilder.getNew()
                            .setColumnProperty("key" + 1, String.class.getName())
                            .setTitle("Field")
                            .setWidth(100)
                            .build();
            reportBuilder.addColumn(columnField);

            //"Value"
            AbstractColumn columnValue =
                ColumnBuilder.getNew()
                    .setColumnProperty("key" + 2, String.class.getName())
                    .setTitle("Value")
                    .setWidth(400)
                    .build();
            reportBuilder.addColumn(columnValue);

... 

//build rowsDataList

...

DynamicReport printPageReport = reportBuilder.build();
JasperPrint finalReport = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(printPageReport,
                            new ListLayoutManager(),
                            rowsDataList);
```

All suggestions welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: This code is very basic and should work, so I wonder which versions of Dynamicjasper and Jasper Report are being used.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I gave up on it and resorted to HTML reports instead.  I was using Dynamicjasper v5.3.2 and Jasper Reports v6.17.0